# Parsing JSON to objects in Alamofire 4

Tags: ios, json, alamofire

I am not a full time iOS dev and need to update some projects. We are parsing JSON via Alamofire like this:

```
    Alamofire.request("https://www.example.com/arc/v1/api/metro_areas/1", parameters: nil)
      .responseJSON { response in
        if let dataFromNetworking = response.result.value {
          let dict = dataFromNetworking as! NSDictionary
          let metroLocations = dict["metro_locations"]
          for d in metroLocations as! NSDictionary {  // <- this is the problem
          }
            //print("here is the length: \(self.locations.count)")
        }
   }
```

but I am getting a SIGABRT on the specified line above. What is the ideal way of parsing JSON in AlamoFire 4 to build our own objects?

#### Edit #1

Sample json:

```
{
  metro_locations:[
  {
    id:1,
    name:"Joes Place"
  },
  {
    id:3,
    name:"Frank's"
  }

  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the JSON you're parsing then we could tell you what is going on.

Comment: @darren102 - updated with sample (simplified) json

Answer (score 0):

Okay based off the simplified example the below should work:

```
guard let data = response.result.value as? [String: Any],
    let metroLocations = data["metro_locations"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
        return
}

for metroLocation in metroLocations {
    print(metroLocation["id"])
    print(metroLocation["name"])
}
```

So what this is saying is the value is a Dictionary keyed by strings and can contain Any value which in Objective C is the same as id

Next it gets the data keyed on the "metro_locations" which in this case is an Array of Dictionary elements keyed by strings

Then loop through the array and print out the values for id and name based on the information you provided above.

This will print optionals since you would use ! to unwrap or ideally guard let or if let to check if there was a valid value.